# Reg: multiple callback not working in array map

Tags: php

so many ways, we can achieve below expected output, but here intention is, how to use multiple callback in array map and achieve the below expected output.

How to add multiple callback in array_map

```
<?php
$scandir = scandir('.');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($scandir);
$scandir = array_map('array_filter',array_map('callback',$scandir));
print_r($scandir);

function callback(&$var){
    $curtime  = time();
    $filetime = filemtime($var);
    $diff = $curtime - $filetime;
    if ($diff < 2000){
        return $var;
    }
}
?>
```

Actual Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => array.php
    [3] => array.php.bak
    [4] => code-test.php
    [5] => code-test.txt
    [6] => code-test.txt.bak
    [7] => code-test2.php
    [8] => load-file.csv
    [9] => load-file2.csv
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
)
```

Expected Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => array.php
    [3] => array.php.bak
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are actually wanting to do, although if the intention is to check for files or directories that have been modified within a certain range from now then making a few adjustments to your code should be adequate:

```
function callback(&$var) {
    $curtime  = time();
    $filetime = filemtime($var);
    $diff = $curtime - $filetime;
    if ($diff < 2000) {
        return $var;
    }
};

$scandir = scandir('.');
$scandir = array_filter(array_map("callback", $scandir));
print_r($scandir);
```

Some of the code you have might not be necessary, although I unfortunately can't check it atm.

Comment: intention is, need to work with array map with multiple calllback

Comment: You should show your full code since you're only showing one callback.

Comment: @Bharanikumar: Can you edit your question to explain what the exact reason you want to use multiple callbacks is though; I think that would be helpful, even for people that might be able to guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is when you call

```
$scandir = array_map('array_filter',array_map('callback',$scandir));
```

because you can achieve that by using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

The following should works

```
<?php
$scandir = scandir('.');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($scandir);
$scandir = array_filter($scandir,'callback');
print_r($scandir);

function callback(&$var){
    $curtime  = time();
    $filetime = filemtime($var);
    $diff = $curtime - $filetime;
    if ($diff < 2000 && $var != '.'){
        return $var;
    }
}
?>
```